# Difference between equation and equation* enviroment?

Tags: math-mode, equations, environments

I am pretty new to Latex and I was wondering what is the difference between:

```
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
```

and

```
\begin{equation*}
\end{equation*}
```

I am always using the first one, but in what instance would you use the latter, or is there any difference between them at all?

*I couldn't find any answers of this question on this forum.*

Comment: The former adds an equation number, the latter doesn't.

Answer (score 15):

The non-starred version provides a numbered equation, which you can easily refer to with `\label` and `\ref`.
The starred version does not provide the equation number, while keeping the same format, and has an equivalent in `\[ ... \]`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The non-starred version provides a numbered equation, which you can easily refer to with \verb^\ref^, like so: \ref{euler}
\begin{equation}
    e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0
    \label{euler}
\end{equation}
The starred version does not provide the equation number, while keeping the same format.
\begin{equation*}
    e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0
\end{equation*}
Unnumbered, displayed equations can also be obtained with \verb^\[ ... \]^.
\[
    e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good explanation :-)

Comment: It might be added that `\[ ... \]` is equivalent to `equation*`, but rather than using that shorthand, it may be desirable to use the longer form to make it easy to decide later to number an equation for reference, so that the only change needed would be to remove the `*` and add a `\ref`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @barbarabeeton! I've updated the answer accordingly