# alignat* labels are not showing

Tags: equations, amsmath, alignat

I am writing an alignment equation, but equation labels (numbers) are not shown. How can I solve this.

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \hat{x} =  \quad & \argmin\limits_{x, v} f(x) + g(v) 
  \\
  \text{s.t.} \quad &  \begin{aligned}[t]
     \label{eq:15}
     x & = v
    \nonumber   
  \end{aligned}
\end{alignat*}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Starred environments are unnumbered, use `alignat` instead of `alignat*`. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539986/difference-between-equation-and-equation-enviroment/539987#539987

Comment: Many thanks. happy to join

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: You should write this as an answer, not as a comment. So your answer can be accepted and the question can be closed.